# Как взаимодействовать с категориями в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Как мне из кода PHP(например, в шаблоне записи) взаимодействовать с категориями записи.
Мне нужно не выводить записи, а отмечать. 
(Я хочу чтобы все записи, которые были подключены к этому шаблоны, стали "включены" в категорию)
Тоесть мне нужно контактировать с админкой из шаблона, чтобы отметить категории. 
Как это делается?

Comment: Вы используете плагин ACF?

Comment: Не понятно, что значит "все записи, которые были подключены к этому шаблоны, стали "включены" в категорию", но `is_page_template` поможет определить шаблон.